# How to change the color of card view on cliking it in android

Tags: android, android-cardview

I want to change the background color of cardview whenever user clicks on it. Can anyone suggest me a way to do that?

Comment: obviously somethink like `onClick() { cardView.setColor(newColor); }` (of course it's just a pseudo code) **what had you tried so far?**

Comment: @jayeshsolanki93 he is asiking about the colour change with the  user click. But your link is not pointing out that bro

Comment: @Selvin I have tried to do it inside onClick but setColor is giving me error

Comment: Thanx @Selvin for your suggestion I tried it using setCardBackgroundColor and its working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use setCardBackgroundColor() like this in onClick() method:

```
    cardView1.setCardBackgroundColor(R.color.colorPrimary);
```